# Add Animation to existing CCSprite by Tag Value

Tags: xcode, cocos2d-iphone, ccsprite, ccspritebatchnode

I have created Animation for a character..need help to add this animation to existing character by its tag value.. 
As far I check on net..all are creating new `CCSprite` to make this animate..but i need it to add this animation to existing Sprite..existing Sprite's tag value is 20.. 
It animates well while creating new `CCSprite`..Thanks in Advance..

```
CCSpriteFrameCache::sharedSpriteFrameCache()->addSpriteFramesWithFile("BearSprites.plist");
CCMutableArray<CCSpriteFrame*>* animateFrames = new CCMutableArray<CCSpriteFrame*>(9);
char str[50] = {0};
for(int i = 1; i < 9; i++)
{
    sprintf(str, "bear_frame%d.png",i);
    CCSpriteFrame *frame = CCSpriteFrameCache::sharedSpriteFrameCache()->spriteFrameByName(str);
    animateFrames->addObject(frame);
}
CCAnimation *animation = CCAnimation::animationWithFrames(animateFrames, 0.4f);
CCAnimationCache::sharedAnimationCache()->addAnimation(animation, "Walk");
CCAnimationCache *animCache = CCAnimationCache::sharedAnimationCache();
CCAnimation *normal = animCache->animationByName("Walk");
CCAnimate *animN = CCAnimate::actionWithAnimation(normal);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code:

```
CCAnimate *animN = CCAnimate::actionWithAnimation(normal);
animN.tag = kTagHeroAnimation; //=272

CCSprite *sprite = (CCSprite*)[self getChildByTag:20];
[sprite stopActionByTag:kTagHeroAnimation]; //=272];
[sprite runAction: animN];
```

Comment: Thanks..But Error as :expected expression..is this allowed in cpp ??

Comment: its for cocos2d, apply same concept in cocos2d-x

Comment: this is only i'm expecting..by using getChildByTag:..but not able to identify how to use in cpp

Comment: sorry guru..i can't get u?

Comment: (CCSprite*)this->getChildByTag(20);,  sprite->stopActionByTag(kTagHeroAnimation);

Comment: guru..(CCSprite*)this->getChildByTag(20);..hoped this vil get work..but not..gets crashed..

Comment: in same class you tried? before this call that sprite with tag20 is added to this?

Comment: is there any possibilities for using getChildByTag: and replace animation to Sprite?

Comment: yes that is possible...something else wrong..may be animation is nil OR sprite is nil...debug your code.

Comment: hi Guru.getting crashed.displays thid line: CCAssert(m_uReference > 0, "reference count should greater than 0");
do u hve any idea where am i doing wrong?

Comment: CCSprite *sprite = (CCSprite*)this->getChildByTag(20); not used like this? hope now already you fixed this problem.

Comment: still crashing Guru..or is it possible to remove by tag and add this animation to that tag?

Comment: like replacing this animation to that sprite.is it possible?

Comment: yes possible..something else gone wrong...make sample test app...if not runs then post source in stackoverflow and ask new question..someone else help...I dont know what;s wrong in your code.